# How to serve VueJS history mode on shared hosting server in subdirectory

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vue-router, web-hosting, subdirectory

I've been digging around a solution for this but still not working. I have a VueJS app with history mode router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

The lets say my domain is `https://www.root.com` and I want to serve this app on `https://www.root.com/sub/`  (not subdomain but subdirectory).

So here is my server directory files

```
--public_html
  --sub ( I place the VueJS code here)
  --index.html (html of root.com)
  --.htaccess (file to route)
```

After that, when I go to `https://www.root.com/sub/` . It shows perfectly the `Home` component. However, if I enter `https://www.root.com/sub/about` it shows `404 Not Found`, but I want it to show `About` component.

But the strange thing is if I make a link to navigate to `About` component in the Home component, then when I go to `Home` component first using `https://www.root.com/sub/`, and click at the link to go to `About` component. It works ! But refreshing the page or manually input the route makes it 404 not found again

**Update 1:**
I read in [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) and they said to edit the Apachae `.htaccess`. So I change like this, but it still not working :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /sub/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my `vue.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/sub/',
  outputDir: 'dist'
}
```

After I'm doing this, going to About page will navigate to index.html of public_html

**Update 2**: I change my .htaccess to this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /sub/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /sub/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, when i enter `root.com/sub/about` to see the `About` component , it will navigate to the `Home` component in root.com/sub.

**Update 3:** My htaccess now looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /sub/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /sub/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it works fine now ! However, now I have a problem with the root.com , all the css and js file always call the file in /sub instead of the root folder

Am I missing something somewhere ? Please help ,
P/s Im using Hostinger for the hosting platform.

Comment: You should read this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: hi @MichalLevý, I did it and update my post following the tutorials but it still not working. I dunno if i'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the way, maybe not the most optimized but it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####
DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(js\/main\.js|css\/(\d+|common|site)\.css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#### not match sub module
RewriteRule ^((?!sub).)*$ /$1 [L,QSA]

#### This is for sub module
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(js\/main\.js|css\/(\d+|common|site)\.css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((sub).*)*$ /sub/index.html [L,QSA]
```